# Can't get my program to load a text file in

Tags: c

so I am creating a program (Well trying to) that gives the user a menu that allows you to create an item, modify an item, view all items, and then display one item and then when selecting 0 (exit) before closing the program it saves the file into a text and I am trying to load it back up again before the program starts but when I got to view all it doesn't show what I created last time I opened the program.

Need it to load up the saved data in the text that was created when the program was first exited. any ideas of what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 12


//Structed Items

    struct item{

    char itemname[20];
    char itemdes[30];
    int itemID;
    int itemOH;
    double itemUP;
    };


// Function Declarations

    int getMenu_Choice ();
    int process (int choice, int count, struct item inven[]);
    int add (int count, struct item inven[]);
    int showall(int count, struct item inven[]);
    int find(int count, struct item inven[]);
    int modify(int count, struct item *inven);
    int save(int count, struct item inven[]);
    int load(int count, struct item inven[]);



int main (void)
{ // OPENS MAIN


//  Declarations

    int choice;
    struct item inven[MAX];
    int count = 0;


// Statements



do//
{   load (count, inven);
    choice = getMenu_Choice ();
    count = process (choice, count, &inven[0]);
}
while (choice != 0);

save (count, inven);

return 0;


} // CLOSE MAIN

/*============================getChoice=*/

int getMenu_Choice (void)
{ //OPEN GETCHOICE


// Declarations
    int choice;

// Statements

    printf("\n\n**********************************");
    printf("\n              MENU             ");
    printf("\n\t1.Add New Item To Inventory       ");
    printf("\n\t2.View All Items In Inventory          ");
    printf("\n\t3.Find An Item           ");
    printf("\n\t4.Search And Modify An Item");
    printf("\n\t0.Exit                    ");
    printf("\n**********************************");
    printf("\nPlease Type Your Choice Using 0-4");
    printf("\nThen Hit Enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

return choice;

} //CLOSES GET CHOICE




/*============================process=*/

int process (int choice, int count, struct item *inven)
{// OPEN PROCESS 


// Declarations


// Statements
    switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: count = add(count, inven);
                break;
            case 2: showall(count, inven);
                break;
            case 3: find(count, inven);
                break;
        case 4: modify(count, inven);
        break;
            case 0: exit;
                break;
            default: printf("Sorry Option Not Offered");
                break;

} // switch

return count;

} // CLOSE PROCESS


/*============================add one=*/
int add(int count, struct item *inven)

{//OPENS CREATE

// Declarations

    int i;


i = count;

if (i < MAX) 
{
    printf("Enter the Item ID:\n");
    scanf("%d", &inven[i].itemID);

    printf("Enter the Item Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", inven[i].itemname);
i++;

    }

else {
    printf("sorry there is no more room for you to add");

};

return i;


}; // CLOSE CREATE



/*============================showall=*/

int showall(int count, struct item *inven)
{
//Declarations
    int i;

// Statements




    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
    printf("\nItem ID   : %d", inven[i].itemID);
    printf("\nItem Name  : %s", inven[i].itemname);
    };    

return 0;
};

/*============================find one=*/

int find(int count, struct item *inven)
{

//Declarations 

    int i;
    int search;
    int found;

   printf("Enter the Item ID to search\n");
   scanf("%d", &search);
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {

    if(inven[i].itemID == search)

        {
          printf("\nItem ID   : %d", inven[i].itemID);
          printf("\nItem Name  : %s", inven[i].itemname);
      found = 1;
          break;
}


}

if(i == count) /* Will be true if the loop executed without executing the break */
{
    printf("\nSorry None existent");
};



return 0;
};

/*============================modify=*/
int modify(int count, struct item *inven)
//Declarations 
{

    int i;
    int search;
    int found;
    int choice;

   printf("Enter the Item ID to search\n");
   scanf("%d", &search);
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {

    if(inven[i].itemID == search)

        {
          printf("\nItem ID   : %d", inven[i].itemID);
          printf("\nItem Name  : %s", inven[i].itemname);
      found = 1;
      printf("\n\n        ****Modify Menu for %s*****", inven[i].itemname);
      printf("\n\n    Select a Number To Modify or 0 To Exit");
      printf("\n    =========================================");
      printf("\n    1. Item ID Number");
      printf("\n    2. Item Name"); 
      printf("\n                              Enter 0-2: ");
      scanf("%d", &choice); 


    switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: 
            printf("\nCurrent Item ID Number: %d", inven[i].itemID);
            printf("\nPlease Enter The New Item ID Number: ");
            scanf("%d", &inven[i].itemID);
            printf("\nNew Item ID: %d", inven[i].itemID);
                    break;

        case 2: 
            printf("\nCurrent Item Name: %s", inven[i].itemname);
            printf("\nPlease Enter The New Item Name: ");
            scanf("%s", &inven[i].itemname);
            printf("\nNew Item Name: %s", inven[i].itemname);
                    break;

            case 0: getMenu_Choice ();
                break;
            default: printf("Sorry Option Not Offered");
                break;

} // switch



          break;
}


}

if(i == count)
{
    printf("\nSorry Non existent");
};



return 0;
};


/*============================Save=*/
int save(int count, struct item inven[])
{

//Declarations
    int i; 
    FILE *fptr; 


//Statements


fptr = fopen("inven.txt", "w");

for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
fprintf(fptr, "ID = %d\n", inven[i].itemID);
fprintf(fptr, "Name = %s\n", inven[i].itemname);
};
fclose(fptr);

return 0;

};

/*============================Load=*/
int load(int count, struct item inven[])
{

//Declarations 
    FILE *fptr; 
    int i;


    count = 0;

    fptr = fopen("inven.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fptr, "%d %s", &inven[i].itemID, &inven[i].itemname);
    }


    fclose(fptr);

return count;
};
```

Comment: 1) `load (count, inven);` --> `count = load (count, inven);`

Comment: what error message you got when you compiled the above code, would be good to pinpoint the line and error message, would be easier to inspect?

Comment: tried that, if it doesn't load it wont keep track of my current count.

Comment: 2) at `load` `i < count` --> `i < MAX` and `return count;` --> `return i;` (When reading is not possible End of loop)

Comment: @lethalprogramer I am not getting an error message it compiles just fine it just wont load up the data from the text.

Comment: the posted code contains random blocks of blank lines and the indention is not consistent.  Please correct.   Note clicking the {} icon (after selecting all the code) will perform a consistent formatting of the code

Comment: when compiling, enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )    the posted code is causing the compiler to output 6 warnings, of which several are serious

Comment: a closing brace,  should NOT have a `;` after the closing brace '}'  so ALL of these `};'`  need to be replaced with: `}`

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 20, 30  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names through out the code.

Comment: this prototype: `int getMenu_Choice ();`  is telling the compiler that the function can have any number of parameters  However, the function signature: `int getMenu_Choice (void)` is saying that the function has no parameters.   It is best if the prototype matches the signature, so (in this case) the prototype should be: `int getMenu_Choice (void);`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) 4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  consider opening brace '{' and closing brace '}' as separate statements.

Comment: if your not getting any messages from the compiler, then the warnings must not be enabled.  Always enable all the warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings

Comment: when calling the functions: `fopen()`, `scanf()`, etc, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: strongly suggest placing all the `itemID` and `itemname` on a single line, perhaps separated by a space and DO NOT label each field

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` input/format specifier, always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field so as to avoid a buffer overflow.  Such overflow results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0):

This code has some serious problems. If this is production code, I'd recommend you can write it in a more forgiving language that is better suited to text processing.

I'll try to cover the basics.

*Every* file operation has to be checked, else you'll be scratching your head wondering what silently went wrong. It typically goes like this.

```
#include <string.h> // for strerror()
#include <stdlib.h> // for exit()
#include <errno.h>  // for errno

const char filename[] = "invent.txt";
fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
if( fptr == NULL ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't open %s for reading: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno) );
    exit(1);
}
```

`errno` is a global variable which contains the error code for the last file operation. `strerror(errno)` turns it into something human readable.

Then you have this for loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    fscanf(fptr, "%d %s", &inven[i].itemID, &inven[i].itemname);
}
```

But you've set `count = 0;` so it never runs. You also pass in a count of 0 in `main`, so it wouldn't run anyway.

You're also not checking that the `fscanf` succeeded, so if the line doesn't match that format it will quietly rescan it again and again and again.

You're passing in `&inven[i].itemname`, but `inven[i].itemname` is already a `char *` pointer. Unlike with an `int` field, there's no need to take the address of it. You should be passing just `inven[i].itemname`. You've made this mistake in other places and should have gotten a warning about it. If not, check you have compiler warnings on.

`inven[i].itemname` is only 20 characters long, it's very easy to overflow that buffer. `%s` should always have a size associated with it, like `%19s` (19 + 1 for the null byte is 20).

Finally, [`fscanf` should be avoided](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

---

Instead, here's how I'd recommend you do it.

```
int load(const char filename[], struct item inven[], size_t max_items) {
    // Open the file with error checking.
    FILE *fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if( fptr == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't open %s for reading: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno) );
        exit(1);
    }

    // A buffer to read each line from the file
    char line[1024];

    // The number of items read.
    int num_items = 0;

    // Read each line
    while( (fgets( line, 1024, fptr ) != NULL) ) {
        // Don't walk off the end of the array.
        // Let the user know you had to stop early.
        if( num_items >= max_items ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "There were more lines than space to store them" );
            break;
        }

        // Parse the line, warn if we can't understand it.
        if( sscanf(line, "%d %19s", &inven[num_items].itemID, inven[num_items].itemname) != 2 ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "Could not understand '%s'\nSkipping.\n", line );
            continue;
        }

        num_items++;
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return num_items;
}
```

Then it's called like so:

```
int num_items = load("inven.txt", inven, MAX);
```

Passing in the filename makes the function more flexible. Since you're passing in an already allocated list, the size of that list must also be passed in else the function doesn't know when to stop writing to the list. And the calling code needs to know how much of `inven` has been populated, that's `num_items`.

That will just get `load` working, but the rest of the code has similar problems too deep for a single answer. Instead of writing everything and trying to get it working, try writing just `load` and getting just `load` working. When it works, move on to another function.

---

As another note, the use of fixed size arrays and fixed size strings to process data files is not going to end well. Your strings are likely too small, and you're not tracking the length of your arrays. That can all get very complicated.

Instead, I'd recommend you look into [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) which provides [arrays](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html) and [strings](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Strings.html) which can grow as needed. They also track their length for you.

But really I'd suggest rewriting this in a language like Ruby or Python, something more suited to text processing and which handles memory management for you.

Answer (score 0):

the posted `load()` function has numerous problems.

See the many comments on the question for a list of the problems.

The following code corrects those problems within the load() function

Note the change to the signature to remove the `count` parameter

```
/*============================Load=*/
int load( struct item inven[] )
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen("inven.txt", "r");
    if( !fptr )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read 'inven.txt' failed" );
        return 0;
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int count = 0;
    while( count < MAX && 2 == fscanf(fptr, "%d %19s", 
          &inven[ count ].itemID, 
           inven[ count ].itemname) )
    {
        count++;
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return count;
} // end function: load
```

Answer (score 0):

@xing that's what I changed in the program and now it wont load properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 12


//Structed Items

    struct item{//Opens Struct
    char itemname[20];
    char itemdes[30];
    int itemID;
    int itemOH;
    double itemUP;
    };//Closes Struct


// Function Declarations

    int getMenu_Choice ();
    int process (int choice, int count, struct item inven[]);
    int add (int count, struct item inven[]);
    int showall(int count, struct item inven[]);
    int find(int count, struct item inven[]);
    int modify(int count, struct item *inven);
    int save(int count, struct item inven[]);
    int load(int count, struct item inven[]);



int main (void)

{//OPENS MAIN

//Declarations

    int choice;
    struct item inven[MAX];
    int count = 0;

//Statements

    count = load (count, inven);

    do//opens
       {
        choice = getMenu_Choice ();
        count = process (choice, count, &inven[0]);
       }//closes

    while (choice != 0);

    save (count, inven);

    return 0;


} // CLOSE MAIN

/*============================getChoice=*/

int getMenu_Choice (void)

{//OPEN GETCHOICE

//Declarations
    int choice;

// Statements

    printf("\n\n**********************************");
    printf("\n              MENU             ");
    printf("\n\t1.Add New Item To Inventory       ");
    printf("\n\t2.View All Items In Inventory          ");
    printf("\n\t3.Find An Item           ");
    printf("\n\t4.Search And Modify An Item");
    printf("\n\t0.Exit                    ");
    printf("\n**********************************");
    printf("\nPlease Type Your Choice Using 0-4");
    printf("\nThen Hit Enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    return choice;


}//CLOSES GET CHOICE


/*============================process=*/

int process (int choice, int count, struct item *inven)

{// OPEN PROCESS 

//Statements
    switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: count = add(count, inven);
                break;
            case 2: showall(count, inven);
                break;
            case 3: find(count, inven);
                break;
        case 4: modify(count, inven);
        break;
            case 0: exit;
                break;
            default: printf("Sorry Option Not Offered");
                break;

}//switch

return count;

}//CLOSE PROCESS


/*============================add one=*/
int add(int count, struct item *inven)

{//opens add one

// Declarations

    int i;


//Statements

    i = count;

    if (i < MAX) 
          {//opens if

              printf("\nEnter the Item ID: ");
              scanf("%d", &inven[i].itemID);

              printf("Enter the Item Name: ");
              scanf("%s", &inven[i].itemname);

              printf("Enter Item Description:\n");
              scanf("%s", &inven[i].itemdes);

          printf("Enter Number Of Items On Hand: ");
              scanf("%d", &inven[i].itemOH);

              printf("Enter The Unit Price Of The Item: ");
          scanf("%lf", &inven[i].itemUP);

    i++;

          }//closes if

     else {//opens else

              printf("\nSorry there seems to be no more room\n in your inventory. Please delete some current inventory.");

          };

    return i;


};//closes add one



/*============================showall=*/
int showall(int count, struct item *inven)

{//opens show all

//Declarations
    int i;

// Statements

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {//opens for

         printf("\nItem ID: %d", inven[i].itemID);
         printf("\nItem Name: %s", inven[i].itemname);
         printf("\nItem Description: %s", inven[i].itemdes);
         printf("\nItems On Hand: %d", inven[i].itemOH);
         printf("\nItem Unit Price: %0.2lf", inven[i].itemUP);

       };//closes for    

    return 0;

};//closes show all

/*============================find one=*/
int find(int count, struct item *inven)

{//opens find one

//Declarations 

    int i;
    int search;
    int found;

//Statements

    printf("Enter the Item ID to search\n");
    scanf("%d", &search);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {//opens for

           if(inven[i].itemID == search)
             {//opens if

               printf("\nItem ID: %d", inven[i].itemID);
               printf("\nItem Name: %s", inven[i].itemname);
               printf("\nItem Description: %s", inven[i].itemdes);
               printf("\nItems On Hand: %d", inven[i].itemOH);
               printf("\nItem Unit Price: %0.2lf", inven[i].itemUP);
           found = 1;
               break;
             }//closes if

        }//closes for

if(i == count) 
  {//opens if

    printf("\nSorry That Item Isn't in OUR Inventory.");

  };//closes if

    return 0;

};//closes find one

/*============================modify=*/
int modify(int count, struct item *inven)

{//opens modify

//declarations

    int i;
    int search;
    int found;
    int choice;

    printf("Enter the Item ID to search\n");
    scanf("%d", &search);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {//opens for

           if(inven[i].itemID == search)
             {//opens if

                printf("\nItem ID: %d", inven[i].itemID);
                printf("\nItem Name: %s", inven[i].itemname);
                printf("\nItem Description: %s", inven[i].itemdes);
                printf("\nItems On Hand: %d", inven[i].itemOH);
                printf("\nItem Unit Price: %0.2lf", inven[i].itemUP);
            found = 1;

      printf("\n\n        ****Modify Menu for %s*****", inven[i].itemname);
      printf("\n\n    Select a Number To Modify or 0 To Exit");
      printf("\n    =========================================");
      printf("\n    1. Item ID Number");
      printf("\n    2. Item Name");
      printf("\n    3. Item Description");
          printf("\n    4. Item Unit Price");
      printf("\n    5. Items On Hand"); 
      printf("\n                              Enter 0-5: ");
      scanf("%d", &choice); 


    switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: 
            printf("\nCurrent Item ID Number: %d", inven[i].itemID);
            printf("\nPlease Enter The New ID Number: ");
            scanf("%d", &inven[i].itemID);
            printf("\nNew Item ID: %d", inven[i].itemID);
                    break;

        case 2: 
            printf("\nCurrent Item Name: %s", inven[i].itemname);
            printf("\nPlease Enter The New Name: ");
            scanf("%s", &inven[i].itemname);
            printf("\nNew Item Name: %s", inven[i].itemname);
                    break;

            case 3:
                    printf("\nCurrent Item Description:\n%s", inven[i].itemdes);
            printf("\nPlease Enter The New Description:\n");
            scanf("%s", &inven[i].itemdes);
            printf("\nNew Item Description:\n%s", inven[i].itemname);
                    break;

            case 4:
                    printf("\nCurrent Item Unit Price: %0.2lf", inven[i].itemUP);
            printf("\nPlease Enter The New Unit Price: ");
            scanf("%lf", &inven[i].itemUP);
            printf("\nNew Item Unit Price: %0.2lf", inven[i].itemUP);
                    break;

            case 5:
                    printf("\nCurrent Items On Hand: %d", inven[i].itemOH);
            printf("\nPlease Enter The New On Hand Amount: ");
            scanf("%d", &inven[i].itemOH);
            printf("\nNew Amount Of Items On Hand: %d", inven[i].itemOH);
                    break;

            case 0: getMenu_Choice ();
                break;

            default: printf("Sorry Option Not Offered");
                break;

}//closes switch

       break;

}//closes if
}//closes for

    if(i == count)
       {//opens if

          printf("\nSorry Non existent");

       };//closes if

    return 0;

};//closes modify


/*============================Save=*/
int save(int count, struct item inven[])
{

//Declarations
    int i; 
    FILE *fptr; 


//Statements


fptr = fopen("inven.txt", "w");

for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
fprintf(fptr, "ID = %d\n", inven[i].itemID);
fprintf(fptr, "Name = %s\n", inven[i].itemname);
fprintf(fptr, "Des = %s\n", inven[i].itemdes);
fprintf(fptr, "On Hand = %d\n", inven[i].itemOH);
fprintf(fptr, "Unit Price = %lf\n", inven[i].itemUP);

};
fclose(fptr);

return 0;

};

/*============================Load=*/
int load(int count, struct item inven[])
{

    //Declarations 
    FILE *fptr;




   if ( ( fptr = fopen("inven.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "could not open inven.txt\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ( ( fscanf(fptr, " ID = %d Name = %s Des = %s On Hand = %d Unit Price = %lf", &inven[count].itemID, inven[count].itemname, inven[count].itemdes, &inven[count].itemOH, &inven[count].itemUP)) == 2) 
{
        count++;
        if ( count >= MAX) {
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return count;
}
```